# Require desired PHP page after logging in

Tags: php, redirect, logging

recently I work on a little project,I will explain idea shortly.

I have a page which displays some content from a database, as far as it is a content from database, it is displayed to specific users, who own the Pass and name to log in to the page.

When entering the page, it displays two text area fields, which require entering the Name and Pass, after that the form is transmitted to the PHP file which is called in my case member.php, which in turn requires access to database, checks the validity of pass and name, and if correct it in turn requires already the main page, which is called in my case main.php.

however in the address bar of the browser still is displayed member.php not main.php.

can you help me with that?

the code example of member.php:

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<?PHP 

session_start();

  require('function.php');
  require('valid.php');
  db_connect();
  if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password) {
// they have just tried logging in
  try  {
    login($username, $password);
    // if they are in the database register the user id
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
  }
  catch(Exception $e)  {
    // unsuccessful login

    echo 'You could not be logged in.
          You must be logged in to view this page.';
    exit;
  }
}
};
 if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
  if ($_SESSION['valid_user'] == "owner") {
        require('owner.php');
        admin();
        ?>


<?php
    } else if ($_SESSION['valid_user'] == 'main-user') {

     require('main.php');



    }
     else if ($_SESSION['valid_user'] == $username) {

        require('user.php'); 
        check_valid_user();
        ?>

       <?php
} else {
    echo " YOU MUST LOG IN TO VIEW THIS PAGE";
}
} else {
    echo "YOU MUST LOGIN TO VISIT THIS PAGE";
}
?>

</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want them to be redirected to main.php? if so, you need to use header('Location: main.php'); before any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like them to be redirected to main.php (as your tag implies), you need to use the following:

```
header('Location: main.php');
```

before anything is outputted from your script. For more on php headers, see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Your `else if` would therefore become:

```
else if ($_SESSION['valid_user'] == 'main-user') {
    header('Location: main.php');
}
```